# How to communicate from an IntentService to an Activity that may not be running at the time?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, communication, intentservice

My Activity (call it A) starts an IntentService (call it IS) as one step in a larger task (call it T). IS may run for an hour or more; when it finishes it must tell A somehow, so that A can take the next step in task T. But, by the time IS finishes, User may have done many things, including killing A altogether. Nevertheless, when User restarts it, A must realize IS has finished, so that A can take the next step in task T.

There are many suggestions how to communicate from IS to A: Intent, PendingIntent, Broadcast and Receiver, ResultReceiver, Messenger thread, etc. [I haven't provided links because a simple search will show them.] But all presume A is alive at the time the message is sent. It seems IS simply cannot send a message to a dead A.

Or can it?

SharedPreferences might be the way to persist a message from IS to A. When it finishes, IS sets flag F in SharedPreferences. Now F is persistent, even if A is dead when F is set. When User re-starts A, it checks F. If F is set, A knows IS finished, and now A can take the next step in task T.

Moreover, if A has a SharedPreferences Listener, then IS can signal A whether A is dead or alive; and IS needs no other means of communication at all.

In fact, it seems SharedPreferences Listeners might be the VERY BEST way in general to communicate and coordinate, as long as messages are only occasional and short.

Does this make sense? SharedPreferences was not designed for messaging, so I fear some hidden consequences. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems IS simply cannot send a message to a dead A.

Correct. You can use an event bus to post an event that A can pick up, and if A does not pick it up, you can persist the details for A to find out about later.

I demonstrate the basic event bus "UI or fallback" pattern in these sample apps for:

- [greenrobot's EventBus 2.x](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot)
- [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager)
- [Square's Otto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/Otto)

In my case, the fallback behavior is to raise a `Notification`, but that is not a requirement.

> SharedPreferences was not designed for messaging, so I fear some hidden consequences

One is performance. `SharedPreferences` always performs disk I/O. Using this as a fallback for cases where there is no running instance of A is fine. Using it all the time is not ideal.

Also note that there is nothing much magical about using `SharedPreferences` here. Any form of persistence would work (e.g., database, other sort of file). Particularly if there might be several messages from IS that need to be queued up, I would consider using [Tape](http://square.github.io/tape/).

Comment: I've used LocalBroadcastManager for IS-to-A comm, but it presumes A is alive. I checked Otto, and it seems good;. but I have a problem: every time I use another library I blow the dex limit. So re-purposing facilities i'm already using is attractive. If there is no "Gotcha" using SharedPreferences (SP) and a listener, that's very attractive. The disk I/O issue is tiny; after all, IS runs an hour or more; the 10th of a second of disk I/O will not be noticed by User. I think I'll try SP; wish me luck! Thank you so much for your reply; I really admire your book and commitment to helping others.